# Difference between "mettere [sostantivo]" and "rendere [aggettivo]"

Tags: verbs, word-choice, difference

What is the difference between the following sentences?

- Lui mi mette allegria.
- Lui mi rende allegro.

Are both equally usual?

Comment: L’espressione corretta è “***mettere allegria***”. Entrambe le espressioni sono comuni. https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/A/allegria.html

Comment: So is "Gli amici ci mettono in allegria" wrong?

Comment: “Gli amici ci mettono allegria”  is the idiomatic expression.

Comment: ***Mettere***: (L) Con riferimento a cose non materiali (generalm. senza articolo), far nascere, provocare, cagionare: *mettere pace, mettere discordia, etc.* http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mettere/

Comment: I have corrected my question. The question has not been answered yet.

Comment: Related [question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10105/how-to-use-rendere-in-a-sentence) on the use of "rendere"